# How do i dynamically create multiple DropDownList in ASP.net VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want number of DropDownLists to appear depending on the items in a BulletedList. I tried the below code.

Dim quantity As New DropDownList

```
    For Each x As ListItem In BulletedList1.Items

        quantity.ID = "mylist"
        quantity.Items.Add(New ListItem("1", "1"))
        quantity.Items.Add(New ListItem("2", "2"))
        quantity.Items.Add(New ListItem("3", "3"))
        quantity.Items.Add(New ListItem("4", "4"))
        quantity.Items.Add(New ListItem("5", "5"))
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(quantity)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You need unique ids for each dropdown and also you need to create the dropdown within the loop.

```
Dim counter As Integer = 0
For Each x As ListItem In BulletedList1.Items
    counter += 1        
    Dim quantity As New DropDownList
    quantity.ID = "mylist" & counter
    quantity.Items.Add(New ListItem("1", "1"))
    quantity.Items.Add(New ListItem("2", "2"))
    quantity.Items.Add(New ListItem("3", "3"))
    quantity.Items.Add(New ListItem("4", "4"))
    quantity.Items.Add(New ListItem("5", "5"))
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(quantity)
Next
```